# SSL over UDP: ICMP Port Unreachable

Tags: java, ssl, udp, bouncycastle, dtls

I am using BouncyCastle to implement SSL over UDP. I have two separate JVMs communicating with each other using UDP. These are standalone JVMs, not any type of web or app containers.

How can I implement this?

I have used test classes from BouncyCastle but getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port Unreachable
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:697)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.UDPTransport.send(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.sendRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.send(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSReliableHandshake$RecordLayerBuffer.sendToRecordLayer(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSReliableHandshake.writeHandshakeFragment(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSReliableHandshake.writeMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSReliableHandshake.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSServerProtocol.serverHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSServerProtocol.accept(Unknown Source)
```

What is the possible reason for that? I am not setting up any server.

Comment: "ICMP Port Unreachable" - the peer does not accept any data on the port you send to. Might be a problem setting up the peer or some firewall in between.

Comment: It's usually best to keep crypto out of things until you're sure the basic communication is working. So in this case, just try to get UDP working first, without any DTLS to confuse matters.

Comment: I have tried using UDP without any SSL and it is working fine.

Comment: DO I need to enable my PORT for UDP as I think these are open already if not closed by some other programs.

Comment: Part of TLS requires host verification. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to verify that the certificate belongs to `myserver.myorganization.mywhateverbynow`. So part of the protocol will do a reverse DNS lookup. I'm guessing here, but this might be the part that is failing. Make sure your DNS is up to par and use hostnames instead of IP addresses.